# Remove rows from data frame for which column equals one of following vectors

Tags: subset

I have a data frame with 2 columns x&y.
Now I want to remove all rows where column x is either equal 1 or 3.
How can I do that?
setting rm<-c(1,3)
and then df<-df[!df$x==rm,] does not work

```
df<-data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,4,4,4,2,2,3,3),c(1:11))
rm<-c(1,3)
df<-df[!df$x==rm,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. So just in case anybody checks this question later on:

```
df<-df[ ! df$x %in% rm, ]
```